# Evaluate Postfix expression using a tree in C++

Tags: c++, expression-trees, postfix-notation

I am supposed to evaluate a postfix expression using an expression tree. Suppose I have a tree like this

```
    -
   / \
  +   *
 / \  / \
a  b  c  d
```

I first need to evaluate a+b subtree and store its result in the + node, then c*d and so on untill i have the result in root node.

I tried the recursive approach using a stack, but that wasn't working. The pseudocode looked like this

1. function eval(node)
2. eval(node->left)
3. eval(node->right)
4. if(node is a leaf node)
   push it on the stack
5. else if(node is an operand)
   pop a and pop b from stack
   node->value = a->value op b->value
   delete a b;

However this didn't work. I also have to show the tree on every step so as to show the nodes being reduced. 
I googled it many times but i was not able to find the required answer.
Anyone please help me how to do this.

```
void expression_tree::evaluate(node *temp)
{
    if(!temp)
    return;
/// stack_postfix obj;
    stack_postfix obj2;
    evaluate(temp->left);
    evaluate(temp->right);
        if(temp->right == NULL && temp->left == NULL)
        {
            obj2.push(temp);
        }
        else
        {
            node * a = obj2.pop();
            node *b = obj2.pop();
            temp->value = a->value + b->value;
            delete a;
            delete b;
        }
```

}

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Please show the relevant code and describe precisely what didn't work.

Comment: You need to push the resulting value on stack in step 5

Comment: A recursive approach doesn't use a stack explicilty: it uses the stack of activation frames that you get automatically when you recurse.

Comment: To be honest I can't get your idea. First of all, why check the node is leaf after evaluate its sub-nodes? Should that be in reverse order? Second, is that `node::value` a field to store the evaluated value? if so what is the purpose of your stack? After all you already have the function call stack to use, and you don't need an explicit stack if you use recursion rather than loop.

Comment: You don't need a tree to evaluate postfix. Possibly you are given an expression tree as input and are then required to *convert* it to postfix, or maybe you are required to evaluate it directly, which is also possible. Please clarify. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 options:

eval of leaf :

1 - just push value to stack

eval of non_leaf:

1 - eval left, - REMEMBER: the eval result added to stack.

2 - eval right,

3 - pop 2 items,

4 - calculate,

5 - push result.

at the end you'll have 1 item in the stack - the last result

**EDIT:**

```
void expression_tree::evaluate(node *temp, stack& s)
{
   if(!temp)
      return;

   if(temp->left != NULL && temp->right  != NULL){
       //only 1 pointer is illegal!
       evaluate(temp->left);
       evaluate(temp->right);
       node* n2 = s.pop();
       node* n1 = s.pop();
       //in the stack should be only leaves
       temp->value = n1->value + n2->value;//use switch by operator 
       delete temp->left; 
       temp->left = NULL;
       delete temp->right; 
       temp->right=NULL;
   }
   s.push (temp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `obj2.push(temp->balue);` in the else part

However, there are more mistakes, the stack needs to be shared between the function calls, so the function can actually process it

Comment: I also tried the same approach using an iterative method, but that didn't work for me also. I just want to know if the approach i am trying to use is right or not. Also is there another way to do it?

Comment: Your stack-based approach is correct, save for some details and a bit unclear implementation.